# Textfield css inner shadow on ios UIWebView

Tags: html, ios, css, uiwebview

Currently I am implementing a mobile version of a website.

On iOS 7.1 **safari** or **UIWebView**, it show

[image]

However my expected output is (also correct on **android browser**)

[image]

you could see that the *upper part of the textbox has a inner shadow on iOS*.

What I did is set the **box-shadow** to **none**. However, the shadow is still exist.

Anyone has ideas on this issue?

here is the CSS code

```
input, textarea {
    box-shadow: none;
    background-color: transparent;
    border: 1px solid #EEE;
}
```

Comment: There have been known issues with `box-shadow` on iOS7, but please post your code. Thanks.

Comment: Try to add `border-radius: 1px;`

Comment: Thx redditor information. Very helpful and I found the -webkit-appearance: none; as well. And tested and it works.

Comment: Kheema, I tried add the border-radius, however not working. >.<

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To remove the inner shadow from the input field add `-webkit-appearance: none;` and it will remove the inner shadow from the input field. This **[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/josicepe/1/edit)** has been tested on safari iOS7 .

```
input[type="text"], textarea {
  display:block;
  -webkit-appearance: none; /*this property remove the inner shadow*/
   border-radius:1px;
  background-color: white;
  height:24px;
}
```

**Update**

Although using `-webkit-appearance: none;` and `-webkit-appearance: caret;` have own problem, so another method is to use a transparent background image. or use gradient. Another Example using Gradient. **[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/josicepe/9/edit)** is here.

```
input[type="text"], textarea
{
 background-color: white;
height:24px;
-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);/*remove the grey highlight appears once touching an element.*/
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(25%,rgba(255,255,255,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(255,255,255,0)));
  /*Chrome,Safari4+ */

background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,1) 25%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
}
```

Comment: Although I found a solution by redditor comment. Your answer is very detail and informative. Upvote for the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
input, textarea {
    box-shadow: none !important;
    background-color: transparent;
    border: 1px solid #EEE;
}
```

Comment: Hello, I tested this method does not work. However, thank you very much for your help. :-)